# XHR responseText is empty string

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, xmlhttprequest, webapp2

Html Page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>xhr</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var xhr_test = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr_test.open("GET","xhrtest",true);
        xhr_test.send();
        alert(xhr_test.responseText);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The main.py file:

```
import webapp2
from handlers import cookies,pages
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/xhr',pages.XHR),
        ('/xhrtest', cookies.XHRTest)
        ],
            debug=True)
```

The Request handlers:

```
class XHRTest(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('0')
```

and,

```
class XHR(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        f = open('static/html/xhr.html','r')
        self.response.write(f.read())
```

Now, when I hit upon the url `localhost:8080/xhrtest` the browser promptly shows the response `0` as the page's content.

Hitting the url `localhost:8080/xhr` which indirectly hits `/xhrtest`, pops up an empty string in the alert box (the responseText is an empty string) but checking chrome's response tab under the network tab, I can see that the request's response is `0`.

So why is `xhr_test.responseText` not able to display the same response?

Comment: For me the problem was that my backend wasn't using gzip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to send is asynchronous (you've set the 'async' parameter to true), which means that your alert is happening immediately, before the request finishes. 
You should add an event-listener to `xhr.onreadystatechange` and use the response within that.

Changing the 'true' to 'false' would make this simple example work, but is not a good idea in the general case.

The [MDN page on Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) explains how XMLHttpRequest should be used.